# Getting autolayout issues in debugger

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

Trying to get autolayout to work so that cell resizing can be achieved.

This is how my storyboard looks like:

[image]

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
    The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
    2016-06-01 14:05:24.587 BrandSpace[4968:1387945] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
        Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
        Try this: 
            (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
            (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1258c32a0 H:[LikeButton:0x1258c2d80'Like'(46)]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1258c3830 H:[UILabel:0x1258c35d0'1'(121)]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1258c4290 H:|-(8)-[LikeButton:0x1258c2d80'Like']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1258bf6f0 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1258c4330 H:[LikeButton:0x1258c2d80'Like']-(387)-[UILabel:0x1258c35d0'1']>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1258c4380 H:[UILabel:0x1258c35d0'1']-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1258bf6f0 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1258c47c0 H:[UIView:0x1258bf6f0]-(15)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1258c1a50 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1258c4810 H:|-(15)-[UIView:0x1258bf6f0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1258c1a50 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1247fb850 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x1258c1a50(375)]>"
    )

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x1258c3830 H:[UILabel:0x1258c35d0'1'(121)]>
```

Comment: Can you post which constraints you put in there?

Comment: how would i post it? I did it in storyboard.

Comment: You can post an image to figure out what is happening there

Comment: Everything on the iphone layout wise looks fine. its just the big imageview seems to be really tall than it should be.